# How to run an other application on background of our application in iOS?

Tags: ios, objective-c, background-process

I have 2 applications: application A and application B.
Application B does some stuff and creates some text.
And now I'm going to call B in BACKGROUND of application A and then print result of B in application A. So what should I do? Could anybody send me some pseudocodes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If they are really app(lication)s, this is not possible due to the [sandboxing of iOS](https://developer.apple.com/app-sandboxing/). If you mean background processing, have a look on [NSOperationQueue](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/NSOperationQueue_class/) or (more low level) [Grand Central Dispatch](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Performance/Reference/GCD_libdispatch_Ref/). See more about concurrency in the [related Apple documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/General/Conceptual/ConcurrencyProgrammingGuide/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008091).

Answer (score 1):

You can not run another application programmatically in background of your application, you can only run some tasks in background for your application but what you are looking for is not possible.

Answer (score 1):

You can take a look at App Group? App Groups are the scheme iOS uses to allow different apps to share data.

This is one of the tutorial I found.
http://www.atomicbird.com/blog/sharing-with-app-extensions